# How to call a class function from inside a React Navigation Header Ba

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am trying to call a parameterized function in a header but could not as I am unable to find to way to pass parameter.

```
class MyScreen extends React.Component {

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => 
{
    headerLeft: (
        <SearchBar 
         placeholder="Search"
         round
         onChangeText={text => this.searchFunction(text)}
        />
    )
};

*searchFunction(text) 
{
    alert( text + ' searched succesfully');
}*

componentDidMount() 
{
  **//I would need implementation here**
}

render() 
{
    return (<View />);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reserved word `this` means nothing in the `static` context of the `navigationOptions` function, So you can't use it there to call the `searchFunction`.

There's a way to add params to the `navigation` object so you can get them in the `navigationOptions` static function.

You can add the `searchFunction` as a `navigation` object param and pass it to the `onChangeText` attribute.

The implementation looks like this:

```
class MyScreen extends React.Component {

  // Pass the searchFunction from the navigation params to the `onChangeText` attribute.
  // It should be triggered with the `text` argument. 
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => 
  {
    headerLeft: (
      <SearchBar 
       placeholder="Search"
       round
       onChangeText={navigation.getParam('searchFunc')} 
      />
    )
  };

  // Use arrow function to bind it to the MyScreen class.
  // (I'm not sure you have to do it like this, try to use it as a normal function first)
  searchFunction = (text) => {
    alert( text + ' searched succesfully');
  }

  // Add the `searchFunction` as a navigation param:
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({searchFunc: this.searchFunction})
  }

  // Since we pass a class function as a param
  // I believe it would be a good practice to remove it 
  // from the navigation params when the Component unmounts.
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({searchFunc: null})
  }

  render() {
    return (<View />);
  }
}
```

[Source](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#using-params-in-the-title)

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks for the answer.